# Azure Service Bus - MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession > 1 doesnt garantee FIFO processing queue with sessions

Tags: azure, concurrency, azureservicebus

I'm trying to proccess multiple messages at the same time from the same session and wanna FIFO guaranteed, It does work only with processor **MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession = 1** on ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions.

When I'm trying **MaxConcurrentCallsPerSession > 1** my message handler receive any message from session with no order.

So, if I want to garantee FIFO ordering processing a session, does It work only with serial processing?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot process messages in a specifc order and process many messages at the same time.

Even if you read the messages from the queue in order, there is no control over how long each message takes to process. The end processing time for each message would then appear to be random if you read messages concurrently.

Comment: I would control message processing order in application with a locking strategy, but my message handler doesnt receive messages in order.

Comment: Correct; the processor offers no ordering guarantees when concurrent reads are active.  Each read is taking place as an independent operation and calling into the handler.  Depending on how the host machine chooses to schedule continuations, the messages may be delivered to the handler in a different order than they were read from Service Bus.